# How to create a class to describe the XML attribute of an element?

Tags: python, xml, web-services, tornado

I am using [tornado-webservices](https://github.com/rancavil/tornado-webservices)

Example XML:

```
<BuildingList CID=”LTP01831”>
    <Building>
        <BAID>01</BAID>
        <BAName>BuildingA</BAName>
        <UpdNo>13</UpdNo>
    </Building>
    ….
</BuildingList>
```

Corresponding Classes:

```
class Building(complextypes.ComplexType):
    BAID = str
    BAName = str
    UpdNo = str

class BuildingList(complextypes.ComplexType):
    list = [Building]
```

How to describe attribute "CID" in element "BuildingList" ?

Or other suggest library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are only interested in xml parsing, here is a brief demo, minidom is the first python lib I used.

```
from xml.dom import minidom

dom = minidom.parse('test.xml')
nodeList = dom.getElementsByTagName('BuildingList')
cid = nodeList[0].getAttribute('CID')
for node in nodeList:
    blist = dom.getElementsByTagName('Building')
    for bnode in blist:
        ba_id = dom.getElementsByTagName('BAID')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
        ba_name = dom.getElementsByTagName('BAName')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
        upd_no = dom.getElementsByTagName('UpdNo')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
        line = '{0} {1} {2} {3}'.format(cid, ba_id, ba_name, upd_no)
        print line
```

~
The result is:

```
LTP01831 01 BuildingA 13
```